# How to center divs in row?

Tags: html

I'm trying to get these divs to center on the page. As you can see there's some white space on the right side. I've tried manipulating the box model, namely the margin and padding, but can't figure out how to manipulate that right side. Is it the fact that I'm using col-md-5?

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="animate.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Merriweather|Europa">

</head>
<body>

<div class = "header">
<div class ="container-fluid">
<h1 id = "firstName">Header</h1>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class = "col-md-5">tile 1</div>
<div class = "col-md-5">tile 2</div>
<div class = "col-md-5">tile 1</div>
<div class = "col-md-5">tile 2</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>

html, body {
font-family:;
margin:0 auto;
padding:0px;
text-transform: none;
font-family: Europa;
letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}

.header h1 {
  background-color: none;
  margin: 30px;
}

.row {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.container-fluid {
  padding:0;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.col-md-5 {
  background-color: red;
  margin: 30px;
  width:%;
  text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
html, body {
font-family:;
margin:0 auto;
padding:0px;
text-transform: none;
font-family: Europa;
letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}

.header h1 {
  background-color: none;
  margin: 30px 0;
}

.row {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.container-fluid {
  padding:0;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.col-md-6 {
  margin-bottom: 15px; 
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  text-align:center;
  padding: 0;
}
.col-md-6 .wrapper{
    padding: 15px; 
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="animate.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Merriweather|Europa">

</head>
<body>

<div class = "header">
<div class ="container-fluid">
<h1 id = "firstName">Header</h1>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class = "col-md-6"><div class="wrapper">tile 1</div></div>
<div class = "col-md-6"><div class="wrapper">tile 2</div></div>
<div class = "col-md-6"><div class="wrapper">tile 3</div></div>
<div class = "col-md-6"><div class="wrapper">tile 4</div></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap works on a 12 column grid layout so the reason for this gap on the right is basically because you've got 2 empty columns at the end.

You can work around this with the following, though:

```
<style>
    .row {
        margin-bottom: 1em;
    }

    .col-md-5 {
        background-color: red;

        /* For whitespace between elements */
        background-clip: content-box;

        text-align: center;
    }
</style>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-5">
            Title 1
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-5">
            Title 2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-5">
            Title 1
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-5">
            Title 2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The key here is the offset class which offsets the first column by 1. This will result in equal spacing either side of both divs. Alternatively, you could swap `.col-md-5` with `.col-md-6` if you wanted no space either side of the elements, also remove the `.col-md-offset-1` class as it would no longer be needed.

*As an aside, with Bootstrap it's best to keep elements within a total of 12 columns per row, i.e. 2x col-*-6's or 3x col-*-4's. Otherwise, you'll have floating issues if the elements aren't the same height.*

Attached Codepen example: https://codepen.io/raptorkraine/pen/prmjeE

Answer (score 1):

Using margin: 0 auto, as suggested in an above answer, is pretty ugly in my book;  especially when there are more elegant solutions.

I think you should forget col-md-*.  Give your divs  width you want, and if you want them 2 to a row, then put them 2 to a row.  Flex is your friend here.

```
*html*
<div class="row">
    <div class="wrapper">tile 1</div>
    <div class="wrapper">tile 2</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="wrapper">tile 3</div>
    <div class="wrapper">tile 4</div>
</div>

*css*
.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 40% //or anything you want e.g. 40vw, 800px, etc
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; // align text contents as a column
  justify-content: space-around; // aligns in center of column
}
```

Might do it.

Comment: I think moving away from using bootstrap's column system will do you real good in both the short-term and long.  Flex is fantastic, and once you get used to making columns yourself, you'll wonder why you ever used bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

using col means your row split into 12 pieces and col-md-5 means that you are using 5/12 of a row. As i can see, you are using 2 col-md-5 so it just used 10/12 width of the row, that's why there are some white space on the right

Answer (score 0):

I use to use this css class in my projects, when I want to center any element agaisnt it parent:

```
.centerElement{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Hoping it helps...